# $R$ is a noetherian ring and $I$ is an injective $R$-module. Let $J\subset R$ be an ideal. Then $I_1=\{x\in I\mid\exists n,J^nx=0\}$ is injective.

Tags: abstract-algebra, algebraic-geometry, commutative-algebra, injective-module

This is related to Ueno, Algebraic Geometry 2, Chpt 6, sec 1's proof of vanishing of cohomology of quasicoherent sheaves over noetherian affine schemes.

> $R$ is a noetherian ring and $I$ is an injective $R$-module. Let $J\subset R$ be an ideal. Then $I_1=\{x\in I\mid\exists n,J^nx=0\}$ is injective.

$\textbf{Q:}$ Is there any particular obvious reason to expect $I_1$ to be injective? Since $I$ may very likely to be non-finitely generated, there is no way to choose $n$ s.t. $n$ uniformly s.t. $J^Nx=0$ to define $I$. The proof roughly goes through as the following. Consider ideal $A\subset R$. Given $\phi:A\to I_1$, I want to extend the map to $R$. In order to do so, f.g. of $A$ gives a power of $J$ s.t. $J^n\phi(A)=0$ identically. Hence application of Artin-Rees yields $J^{n-m}\phi(J^m\cap A)=0$. This indicates $\phi:A\to I_1$ descends to $\phi:A/(J^m\cap A)\to I_1$ for $m$ large. In particular, I have $\phi:(A+J^m)/J^m\to I_1\subset I$. Now consider $(A+J^m)/J^m\subset R/J^m$ and extend the map to $I$ first. Then realize $J^m$ is quotient out. Hence the extended map has image in $I_1$. Therefore, there is an extension which gives injectivity of $I_1$. The critical steps are obtaining quotient map of $(A+J^m)/J^m\to I$ and realization of this map identical to original $A\to I_1$ map.

Comment: How solved the answer your highlighted question?

Comment: @user26857 Not really but I guess I have to take belief that there are cases in which there are no intuitive answers unless someone else can offer a better answer than a general answer.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A general case:

> Theorem: Let $J$ be an ideal of $R$ and let $\bar{R} = R/I$. If $M$ is an injective $R$-module, then $M_1 = \{x \in M \mid Ix = 0\}$
>   is an injective $\bar{R}$-module.

Proof: Let $B$ be an $\bar{R}$-module, $A$ be a submodule of $B$, and $f : A \rightarrow M_1$ be a
homomorphism. Consider the following diagram:
$$
\require{AMScd}
\begin{CD}
0@>{}>> A @>{}>> B\\
 \ @V{f}VV \\
 0@>{}>> M_1 @>{}>> M
\end{CD}.
$$

Since $M$ is an injective $R$-module, there exists $g : B \rightarrow M$ which completes the above
diagram as a commutative diagram. It is easy to see that $Im(g) \subseteq M_1$. Therefore $M_1$
is an injective $\bar{R}$-module.

Comment: $J$ is $I$ in this theorem.